register node.js service in Consul
I have services in Java and one service in Node.js. Consul is raised in a docker container. Java services are registered correctly and inside Consul their health is checked at host.docker.internal:8761/health.
When I try to register my Node.js service, it cannot check the health of the service because for some reason it polls localhost:8888/health and not host.docker.internal:8888/health. At the same time there is no access to this address.
Here's what I'm doing:
const port = Number(await getConsulValue(`${env}/port`)) || config.consul.service.port;
const address = await getConsulValue(`${env}/address`) as string;

console.log(address + " " + port);

const serviceId = config.consul.service.id;

const serviceDefinition: Consul.Agent.Service.RegisterOptions = {
    name: serviceId,
    address: address,
    port: port,
    id: serviceId,
    check: {
        http: `http://${address}:${port}/health`,
        interval: "15s"
    }
}
await consulServer.agent.service.register(serviceDefinition);

Part of the configuration file:
const config = {
consul: {
    server: {
        prod: {
            host: 'consul',
            port: '8500',
        },
        dev: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: '8501',
        },
    },
    service: {
        name: 'service-donations',
        id: 'service-donations',
        port: 8888,
        healthCheckPath: '/health',
    },
},

